# How do i use the Pathfinder class with the MapsLevel class and the waypoints to make the enemy walk on the path in my map?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

This is the class i created MapsLevels:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace TowerDefense
{
    public class Level
    {

        private List<Texture2D> tileTextures = new List<Texture2D>();
        private List<int[,]> MapsArrays = new List<int[,]>();
        private Queue<Vector2> waypoints = new Queue<Vector2>();


        int[,] map = new int[,]
        {
        {1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,},
        };

        int[,] map1 = new int[,]
        {
        {0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,},
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,},
        };

        int[,] map2 = new int[,]
        {
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,},
        {0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,},
        {0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,},
        {0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
        {0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,},
        };

        public Level()
        {

            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(0, 0) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(2, 0) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(2, 3) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(3, 2) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(4, 2) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(4, 4) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(3, 4) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(3, 5) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(2, 5) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(2, 7) * 64);
            waypoints.Enqueue(new Vector2(7, 7) * 64);

            MapsArrays.Add(map);
            MapsArrays.Add(map1);
            MapsArrays.Add(map2);
        }

        public Queue<Vector2> Waypoints
        {
            get { return waypoints; }
        }

        public void AddTexture(Texture2D texture)
        {
            tileTextures.Add(texture);
        }

        public int Width
        {
            get { return map1.GetLength(1); }
        }
        public int Height
        {
            get { return map1.GetLength(0); }
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch batch)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
                {
                    int textureIndex = MapsArrays[0][y, x];
                    if (textureIndex == -1)
                        continue;

                    Texture2D texture = tileTextures[textureIndex];
                    batch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(
                        x * 64, y * 64, 64, 64), Color.White);
                }
            }
        }

        public int GetIndex(int cellX, int cellY)
        {
            if (cellX < 0 || cellX > Width - 1 || cellY < 0 || cellY > Height - 1)
                return 0;

            return map[cellY, cellX];
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 maps but now im using only the first one variable map.
And i have waypoints but they are not fitting to the map so the enemy walk not on the path i created.
The path in my map is marked with numbers 1 and all the rest is 0.

This is the Pathfinder class i added it to this site:

[Pathfinder class](http://pastebin.com/nayrwpUH)

This is my complete project maybe it will be more easy to see it in the whole project:

This is the rar file of my project called TowerDefense:

[TowerDefense](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1007&authkey=!AH-yHT8_RyZR1q4&ithint=file%2Crar)

The problem is with the Pathfinder class on the line number 274:

```
SearchNode endNode = searchNodes[endPoint.X, endPoint.Y];
```

I'm getting exception Index was outside the bounds of the array.

What i want to do in the end is to use the Pathfinder class in the right way and also make that the enemy will move over my path the waypoints should be automatic set to the path in my map.
And hard coded like it is now.

EDIT:

I solved the first exception in Game1.cs i changed the line:

```
List<Vector2> path = pathfinder.FindPath(new Point(0, 0), new Point(9, 9));
```

To:

```
List<Vector2> path = pathfinder.FindPath(new Point(0, 0), new Point(7, 7));
```

I still have two problems now in Pathfinder class in line number 282:

```
startNode.InOpenList = true;
```

It throw exception null since startNode is null.
In many items in the List searchNodes also in class Pathfinder some items are null.

The second problem is yet in the MapsLevel.cs class how ot make the waypoint to be automatic fit to the map ( variable map design ) so the enemy iwll move on the path in my map ?

Comment: This is my project in zip file: 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB1C71C44C3976D5!1008&authkey=!AC5-N4BHQPRwHak&ithint=file%2Czip
And this is the site with the tutorial/s i'm using:
  http://www.gamedev.net/topic/584079-xna-tutorial-series--making-a-tower-defence/

Comment: I solved the exception problem in Game1.cs in this line i changed it from 9,9 to 7,7 List<Vector2> path = pathfinder.FindPath(new Point(0, 0), new Point(7, 7));